# Share variables to each view in laravel doesn't seems to work

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to share the result from query to all views but it doesn't seems to work.

I have in my Category model this

```
public function getAllImageCategories()
{
    $categoires = Category::all();
    return $categoires;
}
```

Then in my HomeController __constructor this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $Category = new Category;
    $allCategories = $Category->getAllImageCategories();

    View::share('allCategories', $allCategories);
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

And in the view

```
@foreach($allCategories as $category)
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>{!! $category->name !!}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

The error

> Undefined variable: allCategories

Why is this error? What I mistaken here?

Comment: You are only sharing to the view `allCategories`, change that to `*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the code into the `boot()` method of service provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    $Category = new Category;
    $allCategories = $Category->getAllImageCategories();
    View::share('allCategories', $allCategories);
}
```

> You should place calls to share within a service provider's `boot` method. You are free to add them to the `AppServiceProvider` or generate a separate service provider to house them.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: Yes, this way is working. Just a question: Isn't that basically same if is in `__construst()` or in serviceprovider `boot()`?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the View Composer for all view pages.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers

Otherwise you can use **Sharing Data With All Views** on the same page
go to

`your/project/directroy/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

and add your code into boot method

```
public function boot()
{
    $Category = new Category;
    $allCategories = $Category->getAllImageCategories();
    View::share('allCategories', $allCategories);
}
```